# GeoTools wms module error

Tags: gis, geotools, wms

I'm using GeoTools(12.2) Wms module for getting some wms information. When I was testing my app for different wms servers,  encountered a problem.

Wms server url : http://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.stedsnavn_fag

Capabilities url: http://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.stedsnavn_fag?service=wms&request=getcapabilities

When I defined WebMapServer object like below

wms = new WebMapServer(url);

Got this error

Error downloading location: http://dbriap004/cgi-bin/stedsnavn_fag?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetSchemaExtension

There is no definition for this different link,It is totaly different from mine and I couldn't see any record about that in capabilities document. What do you think about that? What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the first line of the GetCapabilities response

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" 
xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" version="1.3.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms 
http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd 
http://www.opengis.net/sld 
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/sld_capabilities.xsd 
http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver 
http://dbriap006/cgi-bin/stedsnavn_fag?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetSchemaExtension">
```

You'll see that the owner of the server has specified this URL as a schema location so GeoTools is trying to download that schema which is probably not visible to you. I think you will need to talk to the owner of the server.

Comment: Thanks @iant I got it,the problem is based on missing schema url. Is there any way  of ignoring missing schema url in GeoTools ?